# Compiling and running a program to generate fractal images

Tags: beginner, c, bash, makefile

I'm [making images](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Julia_set_for_f(z)%3D1_over_(z3%2Ba*z%2B_b)_with_a_%3D_2.099609375_and_b_%3D_0.349609375_with_critical_orbits.png). My steps are:

- create PGM files using a C program
- convert/resize PGM to PNG using Image Magic
- remove (big) PGM files

To do it I use Make and a Bash script.

The Makefile is very simple:

```
all: 
    chmod +x d.sh
    ./d.sh
```

Most things are done by the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
 
# script file for BASH 
# which bash
# save this file as d.sh
# chmod +x d.sh
# ./d.sh
# checked in https://www.shellcheck.net/




printf "make pgm files \n"
 gcc f.c -lm -Wall -march=native -fopenmp

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo ERROR: compilation failed !!!!!!
    exit 1
fi


export  OMP_DISPLAY_ENV="TRUE"
printf "display OMP info \n"

printf "run the compiled program\n"
time ./a.out > a.txt

export  OMP_DISPLAY_ENV="FALSE"

printf "change Image Magic settings\n"
export MAGICK_WIDTH_LIMIT=100MP
export MAGICK_HEIGHT_LIMIT=100MP

printf "convert all pgm files to png using Image Magic v 6 convert \n"
# for all pgm files in this directory
for file in *.pgm ; do
  # b is name of file without extension
  b=$(basename "$file" .pgm)
  # convert  using ImageMagic
  convert "${b}".pgm -resize 2000x2000 "${b}".png
  echo "$file"
done


printf "delete all pgm files \n"
rm ./*.pgm

 
echo OK

printf "info about software \n"
bash --version
make -v
gcc --version
convert -version
convert -list resource
# end
```

I do not know Make well so I used Bash which I know better. It works well for me, but I read about Make and CMake. Should I change it?

---

### naive explanation:

- My program is small (one file).
- The dependency tree is very simple (2 libraries which I do not have to recompile).
- Compilation time is very short, so I do not need a staged compilation
- Usually, I create a directory with a descriptive name for the program so the files (now 3) do not need descriptive names and I use short names with an extension that explains the function of the file.

I like that I can run all the tasks with one command (with the easy name `make`) and go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `chmod` needs to go away; `d.sh` should already have the correct permissions, including when extracted from a source archive
- You should probably delete all of your output diagnostic fluff.
- `f.c` and `d.sh` are very bad filenames. The former should probably be renamed to `fractal.c` or somesuch.
- You've mis-used make. The whole point of make is to express a dependency tree, and to be able to ask for anything in that tree to be generated, in turn generating any missing or out-of-date dependencies on the filesystem. You need to re-think output files (e.g. `png`) to be make targets, input files (`.pgm`, `.c`) to be inputs to recipes, and programs `gcc` and `convert` to be the commands within those recipes. Once done, your bash script can go away entirely.
- Don't use `a.out`. Give your binary a meaningful name.
- A side-effect of the above is that checking like this:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo ERROR: compilation failed !!!!!!
    exit 1
fi
```

can be deleted; `make` is smart enough to understand when commands fail.

Re. image filenames such as `1_4000_Fatou_abi_LSCM_zp_cr`: you ask

> do I have to list manually all the files or can I use wildcards like *.pgm ?

It depends on the desired invocation of your makefile. If you want to start with an empty directory and magically `make` and have all of your images generate and convert, then you have to manually list all of the file stems in your makefile. If instead you're comfortable with an invocation that looks like

```
make 1_4000_Fatou_abi_LSCM_zp_cr.png
```

then you do not have to list out all of your stems. Either you would have your current program just generate all of them (as it would happen now), or (probably better) rework your program so that it accepts a command-line argument and generates a single image on demand. The latter would be much easier to code a meaningful makefile for.

If I were to take a guess, your dependency tree basically looks like this. Beware that it's half untested, and in particular `$(IMAGES)` will change based on a few factors including whether you know your image file stems.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export

CFLAGS=-O3 -lm -Wall -march=native -fopenmp --std=c17
OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=FALSE
MAGICK_WIDTH_LIMIT=100MP
MAGICK_HEIGHT_LIMIT=100MP

IMAGES=image1 image2
PGMS=$(IMAGES:=.pgm)
PNGS=$(IMAGES:=.png)


all: $(PNGS)

%.png: %.pgm
    convert $^ -resize 2000x2000 $@

$(PGMS): fractal
    ./$^

fractal: fractal.o
    gcc $$CFLAGS -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc $$CFLAGS -o $@ $^ -c

clean:
    rm -f fractal *.o *.pgm *.png
```

Output:

```
$ make
gcc $CFLAGS -o fractal.o fractal.c -c
gcc $CFLAGS -o fractal fractal.o
./fractal
convert image1.pgm -resize 2000x2000 image1.png
```

(`convert` then fails for me due to it being fed a dummy image but the concept is there.)

Comment: Thx for the answer . In "IMAGES=image1 image2" do I have to list manually all the files or can I use wildcards like *.pgm ?

Comment: Depends. What are the image names? How many are there?

Comment: How many : my record is 39 . https://github.com/adammaj1/implodedcauliflower

Comment: Names are descriptive, like 1_4000_Fatou_abi_LSCM_zp_cr.pgm

Comment: @Adam See edit; there are a few ways you can go but none of them involve wildcards

Comment: If you have `CC=gcc`, then you don't need the rules for `fractal` or `%.o`, because Make's built-in rules will do a better job (in particular, putting the libraries into `$(LIBS)` will put them _after_ our own files, ensuring correct linking).  Prefer `$(RM)` over `rm -f` for portability, and no need for `-r` there.  I also don't see why `fractal` has to be run for every file in `$(PGMS)` - in the original, it only has to run once.

Comment: @TobySpeight re. built-in CC - agreed, but the purpose here was to show an explicit dependency chain since this OP seems new to the concept.

Comment: @TobySpeight re. multiple runs - make is smart enough to see that after the first run, multiple targets are satisfied. e.g. `make image1.pgm image2.pgm` shows `./fractal` / `make: 'image2.pgm' is up to date.`

Comment: My point is that if `image1.pgm` and `image2.pgm` both need remaking, the command will be run for each.  Since it only needs to be run once, we need to make an intermediate phony target `$(PGMS): fractal_is_run` and `fractal_is_run:⤶→./$^`.